# How to open an encrypted sqlite in terminal

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, sqlite

I created a .db3 sqlite file in my Windows,the problem is that I encrypted it,but I couldn't manage to open it directly in Terminal app on the Mac.I know in my Xcode,I can use sqlite_key to open it,but I just want to modify the data directly in my terminal app.So I want to know,is there any command in the sqlite prompt to let me open an encrypted sqlite file.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't do this, unless you write your own SQLite utility (or find one that's pre-built for your version of SqlCipher).